# convert inline styles to css with php

Tags: php, css, class, inline

I have made a class that can produce allot of different barcode types in several formats like:
- Any picture format, GIF, JPG, PNG, SVG,etc
- Compressed javascript (JS)
- Html with inline styles

The class is already optimized to reduce the output of barcode as small as is possible by 'drawing' only the information that is black.

Because the HTML version of the barcode can be that huge (althought it is already optimized), i wonder if there is a class or function that can convert the inline styles to a style tag, for example:

Output is (just a few lines):

```
<div id="mybarcode">
<div style="position:absolute;margin-left:26px;width:2px;height:128px;background:#000;"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;margin-left:34px;width:2px;height:128px;background:#000;"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;margin-left:36px;width:2px;height:48px;background:#000;"></div>
......
......
```

This is what i want:

```
<style>
     #mybarcode div {position:absolute;width:2px;height:128px;background:#000;}
    </style> 
    ....
    ....

    <div id="mybarcode">
    <div style="margin-left:26px;"></div>
    <div style="margin-left:34px;"></div>
    <div style="margin-left:36px;height:48px;">
    ....
    ....
```

If found a class that can do the opposite what i want but that is not my case. Does anybody know if there is a class around that can do such things with html? It can also be useful converting other pages with inline styles to html with external css.

Thank you for your answer! kind regards.

Comment: This should be done right in the first place, as part of the HTML generating part of your barcode class, not as something that you apply afterwards. *You control* the markup generation.

Comment: You are absolutly right with your statement but the class is already very complicated because of the many formats. It is not easy to integrate this optimalisation in to the code, it is easier to do it afterwards. The content will be cached so it is only running once.

Comment: What's the class that does the opposite?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too hard.

**General outline of algorithm:**

- Look at each element and extract the inline style rules
- Identify the styles that all elements have in common
- Extract these styles into a `style` tag under a class (i.e. `common`)
- Remove the redundant inline styling and add the `common` class to the elements

You can do the actual element manipulation using [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). The CSS rules themselves are pretty easy to parse, so Regexes would be what I'd use. Especially in your case, since you wrote the code that generates the HTML so you'll know exactly what CSS rules you might encounter.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but i want a general solution like the css-to-inline-styles class if found (but only in the opposite way). I like to know if such class is around to avoid that i starting to reinventing the wheel. I also know the DOM parser you suggested, my CMS is build upon it and it is great. But i have also a function suGetTextBetween() that can get all styles at once. But, like i just said before, if there is already an solution to this, i like to know.

Comment: I was unable to find a pre-made solution.